# JFrog 5.8.3 as Docker Image

Tags: docker, artifactory

When pulling the latest JFrog Artifactory image with

```
docker pull docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss
```

It is installing 5.8.1 and tells me in the WebUI there is an upgrade to 5.8.3.

```
Digest: sha256:7cbda8f30cea41556a52ea27239c9425ba9d305f6af0a0cc1d675279855e7477
```

Status: Image is up to date for docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest

Is it possible the image repository is not up-to-date?

Comment: you are right and we (JFrog) are going to fix it. For now you can use the specific tag to get 5.8.3 : docker pull docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:5.8.3

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed now.

In general, it's always recommended to be explicit with the version you want. `latest` can bring you something you are not prepared for, or might be faulty pointing to the wrong version, as happened in this case.